# Unix Timestamp bigint(20)

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am doing research in a MySQL database, and I suppose some timestamps are in Unix format.

Those timestamps are in a bigint(20) field.

I'm going crazy about them.

How can I convert these to a regular timestamp?

Example:

634583466272408810

634587264000000000

Comment: Neither of them look like a unix timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select from_unixtime(634583466272408810/1000000000)
```

See [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: It returns `null` (expectedly)

Comment: I'm not an op, but I've never met 1 billionth fraction of second precision in my practice ;-)

Comment: This doesn't return null, but 1990-02-09 18:11:06 in my case. I have no clue tho if this is the correct result.

Comment: @Cervs: Maybe the number is a [FILETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx)