# Covert Convert BigInt timestamp to a real Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an old database however i cant remeber the script i used but need to convert a date if anyone can help

> (287,1090231200,1090233000,'Diary',0,0,0,1,0)

This the the layout

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `start_time` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `end_time` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `description` blob,
  `is_note` tinyint(4) default '0',
  `private` tinyint(4) default '0',
  `rec_app_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` tinyint(4) default '0',
  `all_day` tinyint(4) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_2` (`id`),
  KEY `ID` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15212 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for example if your result is in miliseconds - divide by 1000 to get result in seconds):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(600000000/1000);
```

See the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) for more details.

Note: If you use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert between `TIMESTAMP` values and Unix timestamp values, the conversion is lossy because the mapping is not one-to-one in both directions.

EDIT: Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585245/convert-bigint-timestamp-to-a-real-date-with-row-aggregation-and-operations-in-m)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090772/unix-timestamp-bigint20) question.